# best tool to use for vine production on windows

Tags: video-editor, webvideos

I want to create a vine on my laptop bit not sure which software to download to do it as most of the ones I have come across look spammy and don't want to kill my computer with virus's.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors -- http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16254/easy-to-use-video-editor -- http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9221/video-editor-suggestion

Answer (score 2):

if you´re using Windows you can use / download MovieMaker, and just import your clip and start to editing in most commons formats & if you have a mac imovie does the job also , those are "defaults" software and are pretty intuitive and in a sort way "basic".